# Does updating GPT attributes wear out UFS quickly on a UFS (Universal Flash Storage) drive?

Tags: partitioning, mbr, guid, ufs

I am planning to use some part of the GPT attributes to do some sanity check for an embedded system. It will update/rewrite the attribute for each boot. I am a bit worried that doing so may wear out the NAND chip in UFS quickly.

UFS drive seems to have wear-leveling mechanism internally but I am not sure if it works even for GPT or not. It seems okay but just wanted to double check!

Updated Feb 6, 2024:
GPT is located at LBA-1.  I want to know if re-writing GPT attributes always re-writes the same physical bits on the NAND chip, or it writes to bits in another location on the NAND. I am assuming it is the latter, am I correct?

Comment: I think the chances of it wearing out on a modern drive is zero to negligible.

Comment: Wear-leveling isn't concerned with the data on the chip. Make sure you do have wear-leveling.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know if re-writing GPT attributes always re-writes the same
> physical bits on the NAND chip, or it writes to bits in another
> location on the NAND. I am assuming it is the latter, am I correct?

It's probably safe to assume you're correct when using a modern NAND based drive. Also the drive does not care whether you update some text file somewhere on the drive or editing some data in the GPT.